# SelectionKey is not writable

Tags: java, nio

I am curious why the code always tells me "key is not writable"? Is there anything with my code? Every time the socket has read something, I set the key to be interested in OP_WRITE, and test it whether it is writable. However, it always says not writable. I am totally a newbie in Java socket programming.

By the way, I don't close the client.

```
public final class DateServer {

    private DateServer() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Instantiation not allowed");
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (final Selector selector = Selector.open(); ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();) {
            InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9999);
            serverSocket.bind(hostAddress);

            serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
            serverSocket.register(selector, serverSocket.validOps(), null);

            while (true) {
                int numSelectedKeys = selector.select();
                if (numSelectedKeys > 0) {
                    handleSelectionKeys(selector.selectedKeys(), serverSocket);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void handleSelectionKeys(Set<SelectionKey> selectionKeys, ServerSocketChannel serverSocket) throws IOException {

    Iterator<SelectionKey> selectionKeyIterator = selectionKeys.iterator();
    while (selectionKeyIterator.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = selectionKeyIterator.next();

        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
            acceptClientSocket(key, serverSocket);
        } else if (key.isReadable()) {
            readRequest(key);
        }

        selectionKeyIterator.remove();
    }
    }

    private static void acceptClientSocket(SelectionKey key, ServerSocketChannel serverSocket) throws IOException {

        SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
        client.configureBlocking(false);
        client.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ);

        System.out.println("Accepted connection from client");
    }

    private static void readRequest(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {

        SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

        int bytesRead = client.read(buffer);

        if (bytesRead == -1) {
            client.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.format("Request data: %s", new String(buffer.array())));
            int interestOps = 0;
            interestOps |= SelectionKey.OP_WRITE;
            key.interestOps(interestOps);

            if (key.isWritable()){
                System.out.println("key is writable");
            } else {
                System.out.println("key is not writable");
            }

            interestOps = 0;
            interestOps |= SelectionKey.OP_READ;
            key.interestOps(interestOps);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The interestOps only tell the selector what to select for *next time.* Setting OP_WRITE doesn't magically equip the selection key with the ability to predict the future. You would have to call `select()` again for OP_WRITE to actually get set as a result of this code.

But you don't need the selector's 'permission' to write to the channel. You just write, and only if the write count is zero do you need to worry about OP_WRITE, as per numerous answers on that topic here.

Comment: @Sneh That is *exactly* what it does do. Read the first paragraph again. Specifically, the second sentence.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. I got it. It would be better if there is any official documentation explaining this.

Comment: @HuangJie There is the Javadoc.

Comment: I did read your paragraph correctly @EJP. You edited and added "You would have to call select() again for OP_WRITE to actually get set as a result of this code." which is exactly the part which was missing in your answer.

Comment: @Sneh *More* nonsense. That tells him how to *fix* it. The sentence I mentioned says why his existing code doesn't work, which is what your first comment was about. Will you please stop making incorrect statements about what I have written here. You need to read more carefully.

Comment: @HuangJie Specifically, 'The interest set determines which operation categories will be tested for readiness the next time one of the selector's selection methods is invoked.' There seems to be an outbreak of not reading carefully here.

Comment: @Sneh You are now arguing with yourself. You agreed with me in your 'upvoted' comment. Feel free to witter on aimlessly, but leave me out of it.

Answer (score 0):

When you register your client, you only specify `SelectionKey.OP_READ`, so the channel is never ready for writing. (Look at the isWritable method inside Selectionkey.java)

```
public final boolean isWritable() {
    return (readyOps() & OP_WRITE) != 0;
}
```

In your case OP_WRITE was never registered and hence it didn't work.

Use this to make it work

`client.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);`

Comment: You mean `key.interestOps(interestOps);` afterwards does not take effect? Could you explain why.

Comment: Good question. I just noticed that. I need to investigate why is that not working.

Comment: Yep, your current implementation doesn't work because key selector is currently in read mode and while its in read mode you cannot just add another interestedOps (from my investigation) and expect the key to return you isWriteable() when you are currently reading. Having said that you can still write to channel. Read http://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector

You have 2 ways to fix it
1. as I mentioned in my answer
2. Once you read what u need to read, you add OP_WRITE to key.

Comment: A channel is always ready for writing unless there is no room in its socket send buffer. There is no such thing as a selector being 'in read mode'. Answer and comment are both nonsense.